# Toad Oracle Pl/sql Debugging as jump from breakpoint to breakpoint

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, toad

When I debug a Pl/sql procedure in Toad, I want to jump from a breakpoint to next breakpoint. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any Oracle PL/SQL debug session, set your two breakpoints. Make sure they are both on indeed, executable lines, and that there isn't a conditional code branch that would prevent the program from never actually getting to point B...during the execution of your code, when you reach point A, ask your IDE to 'Execute' and it will continue until it hits the next breakpoint or an Exception.

The code won't jump, it will actually execute every line of code between A and B, you'll just see the cursor/highlighted line 'jump' when it stops at point B.

Note when when it stops at point B, that line hasn't actually been executed yet, and won't be until you tell your debugger to 'run' again - at which point it will go until it gets to another breakpoint, an exception occurs, or it gets to the end of the program.

Alternatively, you can ask your IDE to 'Step Over', and it will execute the current line and stop at the next.

Comment: @phileoseda pretty sure that's what I just said - just be sure you KNOW what's actually happening under the covers

Comment: In Toad: 1. Put breakpoints
2. Start debugging ( shift + f8 )
3. Push "Execute PL/SQL with debugger" button on Toad. And continue with this button to jump next breakpoints.